# Opensource : Implementation of quota based internet surfing

Tags: networking, firewall

We want to implement quota based internet surfing at our place. Say one should allowed to surf particular site for defined time period only.
I am looking for open source solution. Please suggest if any open source solution is available to implement same at small level say 20-30 Desktops.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a [squid proxy](http://www.squid-cache.org/) server and configure your clients use it. This can be configured to give you fine grained control over how and when your users access the internet.

Comment: @Iain would be very gratefull to you if you can point me to configuration of squid that will assist me todo so

Comment: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-setup-transparent-squid-proxy-server-in-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 0):

`Squid` as mentioned by @lain, is an excellent proxy server. There's also [SquidGuard](http://www.squidguard.org/about.html) plugin for Squid making using the features @DipakChaudhari needs easier, but I'm not exactly sure if SquidGuard is actively maintained or not. Still, take a look at it.